# Shell command to automatically activate the webcam in case of invalid password entry

Tags: password, webcam, authentication

I would like a command to automatically activate the webcam, to film 10 seconds and save it in a file if a bad password is entered on my pc.

Comment: The title should be in english.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! We’re an English-only community, so please don't replace your English question with one in a different language.